In a website, when clicking an URL in it, it will open a new tab and inject a redirect. How to view the URL redirect trace in browser?
When I click a non-Facebook link in Facebook, it will be opened in new tab and be redirected to:
https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fexample-url-shortener.com%2Fslug%3Ffbclid%3D...&h=...&__tn__=...&c[0]=...

This intervenes the parameters of the actual link. I want to examine the redirect trace carefully.
The question How to track url redirects in the browser? doesn't seem to apply to this case, because:

3rd party redirect inspector doesn't inject redirect like how Facebook does
Persists logs doesn't capture URL opened in a new tab
Firebug has become Firefox Developer Edition, and I don't think this task cannot be done with a regular browser

Do you have any idea?

Have you tried Fiddler?

For Firefox, there is the third-party add-on Link Redirect Trace, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-redirect-trace-addon/ . That said, it "is not actively monitored for security by Mozilla. Make sure you trust it before installing."

also note the difference between redirecting and rewriting. if you don't see a 30x response in the network tab, then it is likely that the url is being rewritten serverside instead of returning a 30x and letting the browser handle it client-side.

@FrankThomas I'm not sure what exactly server-side url rewriting does. Can you give an example? And why is it likely but not surely? Is there a case that the browser issuing a redirect without 30x response?
